# .NET 6 Core C# -building a rest webservice with binary multipart/form-data upload returning json

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to build a .NET 6.0 C# rest webservice, receiving a string and three files, one of them a binary image.
The files are not saved, just checked/evaluated and the result is returned in a json structure.
The string can be an url path parameter.
The webservice should run on windows and in a linux docker container.
It is called only from C# clients and is not accessible from the internet.

So the curl looks like that:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d74496d66958873e" \
--data-binary "@KeyValue.json" \
--data-binary "@Text.txt" \
--data-binary "@Image.tif" \
http://localhost:5000/check/CheckType01
```

I tried an approach starting with the Visual Studio 2022 Project "ASP.NET Core-Web-Api"

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/check/{checkType}", (string checkType, HttpContext ctx) =>
{
    ctx.Request.EnableBuffering();
    ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.Body);
    var body = Task.Run(async () => await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));

    Console.WriteLine("Parameter:  " + checkType);
    Console.WriteLine("MultiPart:  " + body.Result);

    return new { check = "Ok", confidence = 100 }; ;
});

app.Run();
```

With the three files containing "KeyValueContent", "TextContent" and "ImageContent", this code partially works:

```
Output:
Parameter:  CheckType01
MultiPart:  KeyValueContent&TextContent&ImageContent
Return:
{"check":"Ok","confidence":100}
```

But this can't be the correct approach to solve this, I assume.

- The files are separated by an '&' and not by the boundary from the header, so it is not possible to separate them.
- Somehow the framework should do the separation instead.
- The multipart body is a string and not a byte array.
- The webservice is blocked during the body read.

I have read a lot about how to upload files in ASP.Net Core, about webapi-controllers, model view controllers, annotations, minimal API or not and so on,
but I'm still not sure what the correct way to go is, I couldn't find a working minimal example.

I would like to know:

- which Visual Studio 2022 starting project type should I use?
- what framework to use (minimal api, api with controllers, [ApiController] attribute ...)?
- the necessary attributes for POST - binary multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides fixing the  curl request to read multiple file you can use [`IFormFileCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfilecollection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) returned by `HttpRequest.Form.Files` (inject `HttpRequest` as handler parameter or use `ctx.Request` to access it).

Also note that `Task.Run` not only pointless here but harmful, just mark the lambda handler as `async`:

```cs
app.MapPost("/check/{checkType}", async (string checkType, HttpRequest request) =>
{
    var formFileCollection = request.Form.Files;
    foreach (var formFile in request.Form.Files)
    {
        using var openReadStream = new StreamReader(formFile.OpenReadStream());
        var readToEndAsync = await openReadStream.ReadToEndAsync();
        // do something here
    }

    ...

    return new { check = "Ok", confidence = 100 };
});
```

Comment: thanks, I understand. I have only one question, as my code example was the complete code, how can I keep the async code running? Without app.Run(); it returns immediately. With app.Run() it indeed throws "System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream".

Comment: @Gilgamesch `app.Run();` has noting to do with async nature of the handler. It starts the webserver which will handle the request. What and when is throwing `System.IO.IOException`?

Comment: &Guru Stron Maybe, I don't understand correctly the behaving or implementation of a handler. When I run/debug the async code without app.Run(), the webservice starts but stops running immediately, without doing anything. When I add app.Run() at the bottom, it keeps running, but throws the exception after the curl command.

Comment: @Gilgamesch `app.Run` starts the webserver and keeps it running. Handler is invoked when request with correct path is made. As for throwing - I was not able to repro (I've used postman to make the request and the code in my answer worked fine).

Comment: &Guru Stron Ok thanks, that was my fault. I thought with Task.Run() you refer to app.Run, but of course you meant "Task.Run(async () ...". Regarding the exception which I see with the curl, I should be able to find the reason, I will try postman. (      System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken))

Answer (score 1):

I checked your codes,you want to post mutiple files at one time,but --data-binary allows you post one file per request,you could try with -F to post serverl files and access the files from HttpContext.Request.Form.
You could try with postman,and you will find what's wrong immediately:
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks. I also noticed, "-F "@KeyValue.json" in the curl command is not enough, the curl command has to be in the form "-F "Name=@KeyValue.json". It seems in the moment I cannot upvote any answers, because this was my first question and I have not enough reputation at the moment.